# error on reopening a ms document via vb6

Tags: vb6, ms-word

I'm doing SOME VB6 - MS WORD application.., here's my code

```
dim WordObj As Word.Application
Dim objWord As Word.Document

Set WordObj = new Word.Application
Set objWord = WordObj.Documents.Open(FileName:=App.Path & "\PN.doc")


With objWord.Bookmarks
   .Item("NAME").Range.Text = name.Text
   .Item("ADDRESS").Range.Text = add.Text
   .Item("ID").Range.Text = id.Text
   .Item("PHONE").Range.Text = phone.Text
   .Item("FAX").Range.Text = fax.Text
End With

ActiveDocument.SaveAs (App.Path & "\" & name.text & "-PN.Doc")
ActiveDocument.Application.Quit

WordObj.Quit False

Set WordObj = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing
```

after 1st opening on the file PN.doc and save it as [name]-PN.doc. it works fine. if I reopen it and re save it. an error came up and says

```
 The remote sever machine does not exist or is unavailable
```

when i try to open the PN.doc in a word application, an error will pup-out and says

```
the document has caused a serious error the last time it was opened. Would you like  to continue opening it?
```

im using visual basic6 and ms office 2010

tnx..,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ActiveDocument.Application.Quit`

Remove this line. You are closing Word twice.

Comment: where is my first closing?.., I used that process in printing PN (promissory note)?..,  tnx for the rply